# SSL without CA root with openssl s_client

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

So, I've key and cert file which are using without problem with CURL.

```
curl -k --key key --cert cert --url myurl
```

No problem with it. Buf if test connection with openssl s_client i've error 19 self-signed cert in chain.

```
openssl s_client -key key -cert cert -connect myurl:443
```

So, seems openssl must have alternative option '-k' of curl which means insecure, allow connections to SSL sites without certs (H). Somebody knows it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`curl` will simply not make the connection at all without `-k` if the certificate isn't trusted.

In contrast, `openssl s_client` will make the connection anyway, but will display a warning if the certificate isn't trusted. (You would have to specify a list of trusted CA certificates using `-CApath` or `-CAfile` to get rid of that warning.)

Comment: Is this still try 10 years later? I'm having trouble getting s_client to connect to a secure server. `openssl` reports a handshake failure along with `Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)`. I'm not convinced the issue is something else, though.